How does ROS_control compute the dynamic model of the robot?
Suppose I want to use a torque control of the form :
$$
\tau = J^T(q) \left( K_p (p_d - p) - K_d \dot{p} \right) + g(q)
$$
given that:
$$
M(q) \ddot{q} + C(q, \dot{q}) \dot{q} + g(q) = \tau
$$
where $p=f(q)$ is the direckt kinematics. My question is: does ROS control know how to handle the $M$ and $C$ matrices? How about the Jacobian? How does it compensate for gravity? I went through every script of the ros_control and ros_controllers packages but it didn't seem to be anything related.
I would like to write my own script to realize a similar controller, where do I even start?

Short answer: There is no such model-based controller in ros-controllers.
"effort_controllers" use the effort interfaces, and some of them with a PID control loop for position/velocity.

And how does "effort_controllers" deals with gravity?

Simply: not at all
